# Server Express não lê arquivo além do index.html

Tags: javascript, express.js

Criei um server com express:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
app.use('/static', express.static('public'));


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));
})

app.get('/addForm', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/addForm.html'));
})

app.listen(3001);
```

Ele lê tudo certo, porém quando adicionei mais uma pagina (/addForm.html) no mesmo nível do /index.html ele não consegue ler mais.

Esta é a estrutura atual:

[image: Estrutura atual do projeto]

Comment: Qual é o erro no console?

Comment: eu acho que não colocou todo o caminho correto

Comment: Então Virgilio, não aparece erro no console, simplesmente consta mesmo que o caminho está errado

Comment: O caminho é o mesmo do index.html, já que os dois estão no mesmo lugar, o que poderia estar errado ?

Comment: Faz um teste e onde voce colocou o **index.html**, ou seja, no `app.get('/'...` troque ali o **index.html** para **addForm.html** e vê se funciona.

Comment: como você inicia a aplicação em qual pasta? e qual linha de comando?

Answer (score 0):

Parece que o seu `express.static()` está carregando index.html para você e também está fazendo com que http://localhost:3000/addForm.html funcione para você. Mas nenhuma das rotas criadas manualmente funcionaria porque `res.sendFile(__dirname, "/addForm.html")` não faz referência a um arquivo no diretório certo.

Então, você precisaria corrigir o caminho para esse arquivo:

```
router.get('/addForm', função (req, res, next) {
   res.sendFile (path.join (__ dirname, "../public", "/addForm.html"), {dotfiles: "allow"});
});
```